# Reflection of EM Wave

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

Why is it the case that the orientation of the incident and reflected electric field are the same, while the orientation of the magnetic field is inverted (i.e. the field direction flips)? Why should it not be the other way around?

Comment: It depends if the reflection is off a higher dielectric constant material or lower. If it's off a conductor,  the E field direction is reversed on reflection.

Comment: If the wave is incident upon a higher refractive index material, the opposite is true.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the physical mechanism:

- Imagine a vertical E field impinging on perfect conductor
- When the field is oriented up, it drives a current upward
- That moves charge that cancels the E field and sends it back the other way

That moving charge is a current. By the right-hand rule, that causes a B field around it. The B field ahead and the B field behind are in opposite directions, which is the inversion you’re looking for.